# Excel match-index different sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel

So, I have a list of firm names in column `A` in `sheet 1`, with associated values until column `K`. In `sheet 2`, I have a similar list but where the order of firm names is slightly different from `sheet 1`. In `sheet 2` column `I`, for every firm name in column `A`, I want to find that firm name in `sheet 1` column `A` and return the value (if value exists) in column `K` in `sheet 1`.

I use this,

```
=INDEX(Results!A:A;MATCH([@firm];Results!K:K;0))
```

Why is it still giving me `N/A`, anyone know?

Comment: What kind of cell format in Colum A and K?

Comment: Text in A and numbers in K, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You have the columns backwards.  If the firm is in column A then it belongs in the Match and column that holds the value should be in the INDEX:

```
=INDEX(Results!K:K;MATCH([@firm];Results!A:A;0))
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me, unfortunately, I still get N/A error with this. Any ideas what it may be? Actually, I notice the firm names (e.g INFINEON TECH AG and INFINEON TECH) are not exact name between sheets, can I look up value that is not exact same match? Is this the reason for error?

Comment: So I changed a name so they both match and the formula works. Although doesnt seem to work when the list starts to differ in terms of order of the names..But how can I do this with formula?

Comment: Order should not matter.  But yes the text strings must be a match.